# Linux kernel: Why add_timer() is modifying my "expires" value?

Tags: linux, timer, kernel, real-time

I am trying to setup a periodic timer triggering a function every seconds, but there is a small drift between each call. After some investigations, I found that this is the `add_timer()` call which adds an offset of 2 to the `expires` field (~2ms in my case).

Why is this drift added? Is there a clean way to prevent it? I am not trying to get an accurate millisecond precision, I have a vague understanding of the kernel real-time limitations, but at least to avoid this intentional delay at each call.

Here is the output from a test module. Each couple of numbers is the value of the `expires` field just before and after the call:

```
[100047.127123] Init timer 1000
[100048.127986] Expired timer 99790884 99790886
[100049.129578] Expired timer 99791886 99791888
[100050.131146] Expired timer 99792888 99792890
[100051.132728] Expired timer 99793890 99793892
[100052.134315] Expired timer 99794892 99794894
[100053.135882] Expired timer 99795894 99795896
[100054.137411] Expired timer 99796896 99796898
[...]
[100071.164276] Expired timer 99813930 99813932
[100071.529455] Exit timer
```

And here is the source:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

static struct timer_list t;

static void timer_func(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long pre, post;
    t.expires = jiffies + HZ;
    pre = t.expires;
    add_timer(&t);
    post = t.expires;
    printk("Expired timer %lu %lu\n", pre, post);
}

static int __init timer_init(void)
{
    init_timer(&t);
    t.function = timer_func;
    t.expires = jiffies + HZ;
    add_timer(&t);
    printk("Init timer %d\n", HZ);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit timer_exit(void)
{
    del_timer(&t);
    printk("Exit timer\n");
}

module_init(timer_init);
module_exit(timer_exit);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause. Let's trace the `add_timer` function:

The [`add_timer`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8ecffd7914484b728799dd31968f1339fae91593/kernel/timer.c#L910) function calls:

```
mod_timer(timer, timer->expires);
```

The [`mod_timer`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8ecffd7914484b728799dd31968f1339fae91593/kernel/timer.c#L852) function calls:

```
expires = apply_slack(timer, expires);
```

and then goes on to actually modify the timer.

The [`apply_slack`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8ecffd7914484b728799dd31968f1339fae91593/kernel/timer.c#L793) function says:

```
/*
 * Decide where to put the timer while taking the slack into account
 *
 * Algorithm:
 *   1) calculate the maximum (absolute) time
 *   2) calculate the highest bit where the expires and new max are different
 *   3) use this bit to make a mask
 *   4) use the bitmask to round down the maximum time, so that all last
 *      bits are zeros
 */
```

Before continuing, let's see what is the timer's slack. The [`init_timer`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b3a3a9c441e2c8f6b6760de9331023a7906a4ac6/include/linux/timer.h#L131) macro eventually calls [`do_init_timer`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8ecffd7914484b728799dd31968f1339fae91593/kernel/timer.c#L621) which sets the slack by default to `-1`.

With this knowledge, let's reduce `apply_slack` and see what remains of it:

```c
static inline
unsigned long apply_slack(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned long expires)
{
        unsigned long expires_limit, mask;
        int bit;

        if (timer->slack >= 0) {
                expires_limit = expires + timer->slack;
        } else {
                long delta = expires - jiffies;

                if (delta < 256)
                        return expires;

                expires_limit = expires + delta / 256;
        }
        mask = expires ^ expires_limit;
        if (mask == 0)
                return expires;

        bit = find_last_bit(&mask, BITS_PER_LONG);

        mask = (1 << bit) - 1;

        expires_limit = expires_limit & ~(mask);

        return expires_limit;
}
```

The first `if`, checking for `timer->slack >= 0` fails, so the `else` part is applied. In that part the difference between `expires` and `jiffies` is slightly less than `HZ` (you just did `t.expires = jiffies + HZ`. Therefore, the `delta` in the function (with your data) is most likely about 4 and `delta / 4` is non zero.

This in turn implies that `mask` (which is `expires ^ expires_limit`) is not zero. The rest really depends on the value of `expires`, but for sure, it gets changed.

So there you have it, since `slack` is automatically set to `-1`, the `apply_slack` function is changing your `expires` time to align with, I guess, the timer ticks.

If you don't want this slack, you can set `t.slack = 0;` when you are initializing the timer in `timer_init`.

Comment: Ok. The reason seems to be energy saving: "grouping timers reduces
the number of wakeups which in turn reduces power consumption" from http://lwn.net/Articles/369361/

Comment: @calandoa, since they refer to it as "legacy timers" (even 4 years ago), perhaps you should try to learn more "modern" timers?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the old answer! It doesn't address the issue in your question, but it is an issue with what you are trying to achieve nonetheless: having a periodic function.**

Let's visualize your program in a timeline (assuming start time 1000 and HZ=50 with imaginary time units):

```
time (jiffies)   event
1000             in timer_init(): t.expires = jiffies + HZ; // t.expires == 1050

1050             timer_func() is called by timer
1052             in timer_func(): t.expires = jiffies + HZ; // t.expires == 1102

1102             timer_func() is called by timer
1104             in timer_func(): t.expires = jiffies + HZ; // t.expires == 1154
```

I hope you see where this is going! The problem is that there is a delay between the time the timer expires and the time you calculate when the next expiration should be. That's where the drift comes from. The drift could get even larger, by the way, if the system is busy and your function call is delayed.

The way to fix it is very very easy. The problem was that when you update `t.expires` by `jiffies`, which is the *current* time. What you should do is update `t.expires` by the last time it expired (which is already in `t.expires`!).

So, in your `timer_func` function, instead of:

```
    t.expires = jiffies + HZ;
```

simply do:

```
    t.expires += HZ;
```

Comment: No, check better the module output, this is not what is happening. I agree that what you are explaining can sometimes happen when the system is busy, but here the interrupt is not delayed and this is `add_timer()` the culprit.